# Need suggestions for decoupling classes used in a script

Tags: python, design-patterns, pyserial, organization

I have a python program in which the main use case is interacting with it through a CLI to instruct it to send out byte packets over serial. The serial target adheres to a certain command protocol. The python program builds packets that adhere to this protocol based on user input on the CLI (specific command to send, arguments for the command, etc).

The module for this functionality consists of three classes: one which subclasses enum to create unique identifiers for each possible command, one which subclasses the cmd module to implement a CLI interface to the user (this class also does argument input sanitizing) and finally one class which takes in the desired command and arguments and builds the packet to send out over serial

The issue I'm having is that these classes are getting pretty coupled. Ideally I wanted the `Master_Comm` class to be kind of independent so it could be accessed from other modules to send out packets from a different origin (say a script file parser). As it is `Serial_Interface` has an instance of `Master_Comm` to access the `sendcommand` method, as well as implementing input sanitation (which may need to be done multiple places.

Any suggestions on organizing this better? Especially as the program grows (possibly implementing hundreds of commands).

```
import serial
from cmd import Cmd
from enum import Enum, unique

@unique
class Command_Names(Enum):
    CMD1 = 1
    CMD2 = 2

class Serial_Interface(Cmd):
    def __init__(self, port, baud,):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.slave_comm = Master_Comm(port=port, baud=baud)
        # setup stuff

    def do_cmd1(self, args):
        try:
            assert 0 <= int(args) <= 25, "Argument out of 0-25 range"
            self.slave_comm.sendcommand(Command_Names.CMD1, args)
        except (AssertionError) as e:
            print(e)

    def do_cmd2(self, args):
        try:
            # No args for cmd2, so don't check anything
            self.slave_comm.sendcommand(Command_Names.CMD2, args)
        except (AssertionError) as e:
            print(e)


class Master_Comm(object):
    _SLAVE_COMMANDS = {Command_Names.CMD1:           (b'\x10', b'\x06', b'\x06'),
                       Command_Names.CMD2:           (b'\x10', b'\x07', b'\x07')}

    _SOURCE_ID = b'\xF0'
    _SEQ_NUM = b'\x00'

    def __init__(self, port, baud):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port=None,
                                 baudrate=int(baud)
                                 )
        self.ser.port = port

    def open_serial(self):
        # do stuff

    def close_serial(self):
        # do stuff

    def sendcommand(self, command, args):
        try:
            txpacket = bytearray()
            txpacket.extend(self._SOURCE_ID)
            txpacket.extend(self._SEQ_NUM)
            txpacket.extend(self._SLAVE_COMMANDS[command][0])
            txpacket.extend(self._SLAVE_COMMANDS[command][1])
            txpacket.extend(self._SLAVE_COMMANDS[command][2])
            self.ser.write(tx_bytes)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Definitely check out asyncio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decouple the commands hardcoded in your `Master_Comm` class by passing them as an argument to its `__init__()` constructor. Below is simple implementation of this which creates and uses a new dictionary named `CMDS` which is defined separately.

This table is passed as an argument to the `Master_Comm` class when an instance of it is created, then that is passed as an argument to the `SerialInterface` class (instead of it creating it's own).

This same idea could be taken further by changing the format of the `CMDS` table so it included more information about the command and then using that in the `SerialInterface` class' implementation instead of the hardcoded stuff it still has in it (such as the length of the tuple of bytes associated with each one).

**Note** that I also changed the names of your classes to they follow [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations for naming.

```
import serial
from cmd import Cmd
from enum import Enum, unique

class SerialInterface(Cmd):
    def __init__(self, mastercomm):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.slave_comm = mastercomm
        # setup stuff

    def do_cmd1(self, args):
        try:
            assert 0 <= int(args) <= 25, "Argument out of 0-25 range"
            self.slave_comm.sendcommand(CommandNames.CMD1, args)
        except (AssertionError) as e:
            print(e)

    def do_cmd2(self, args):
        try:
            # No args for cmd2, so don't check anything
            self.slave_comm.sendcommand(CommandNames.CMD2, args)
        except (AssertionError) as e:
            print(e)


class MasterComm:
    """ Customized serial communications class for communicating with serial
        port using the serial module and commands defined by the table "cmds".
    """
    def __init__(self, port, baud, cmds):
        self.ser = serial.Serial(port=None,
                                 baudrate=int(baud),)
        self.ser.port = port
        self.source_id = cmds['source_id']
        self.seq_num = cmds['seq_num']
        self.slave_commands = cmds['slave_commands']

    def sendcommand(self, command, args):
        try:
            txpacket = bytearray()
            txpacket.extend(self.source_id)
            txpacket.extend(self.seq_num)
            txpacket.extend(self.slave_commands[command][0])
            txpacket.extend(self.slave_commands[command][1])
            txpacket.extend(self.slave_commands[command][2])
            self.ser.write(txpacket)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


@unique
class CommandNames(Enum):
    CMD1 = 1
    CMD2 = 2

CMDS = {
    'source_id': b'\xF0',
    'seq_num': b'\x00',
    'slave_commands' : {CommandNames.CMD1: (b'\x10', b'\x06', b'\x06'),
                        CommandNames.CMD2: (b'\x10', b'\x07', b'\x07')}
}

mastercomm = MasterComm(0x03b2, 8192, CMDS)
serialinterface = SerialInterface(mastercomm)
serialinterface.cmdloop()
```